# Rewriting Joins as Subqueries in this query

Tags: sql, database, db2

Can you guys pls help me rewrite this using a subquery

```
SELECT 
    S.DENUMIRE, M.DENUMIRE, AN
FROM 
    SPECIALIZARE S
JOIN 
    MATERII M ON S.CODSPEC = M.CODSPEC
ORDER BY 
    S.DENUMIRE
```

Comment: What you are doing requires a join operation by its very nature.  I think you should update your question explaining exactly what problem you are having.  Then we can help solve the problem.

Comment: Note that a "subquery" only creates an intermediate result set from one of the tables.  But you would still have to join the results of the subquery to link it up with the other table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    S.DENUMIRE,
    M.DENUMIRE,
    AN
FROM SPECIALIZARE S
JOIN (
    SELECT
        DENUMIRE,
        CODSPEC
    FROM MATERII
) AS M
    ON S.CODSPEC = M.CODSPEC
ORDER BY S.DENUMIRE
```

Comment: can you give me one more response without using join

Comment: You want data from both columns in the SELECT list. That is not possible without joining the 2 tables.

Comment: @CalinSinea its not possible... (whatch ypercube's answer)... you can make 2 queries and merge it (e.g. php or java)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `DENUMIRE` is an integer:

```
SELECT S.DENUMIRE, 1 DENUMIRE, AN
  FROM SPECIALIZARE S
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                 FROM MATERII M 
                WHERE S.CODSPEC = M.CODSPEC
                      AND M.DENUMIRE = 1
              )
UNION
SELECT S.DENUMIRE, 2 DENUMIRE, AN
  FROM SPECIALIZARE S
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                 FROM MATERII M 
                WHERE S.CODSPEC = M.CODSPEC
                      AND M.DENUMIRE = 2
              )
UNION
SELECT S.DENUMIRE, 3 DENUMIRE, AN
  FROM SPECIALIZARE S
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                 FROM MATERII M 
                WHERE S.CODSPEC = M.CODSPEC
                      AND M.DENUMIRE = 3
              )

UNION
...
```

and so on for every integer value... which of course is not feasible.

You need a join! If you simply want to avoid avoid the `JOIN` keyword for pedagogical reasons:

```
SELECT 
    S.DENUMIRE, M.DENUMIRE, AN
FROM 
    SPECIALIZARE S, MATERII M 
WHERE
    S.CODSPEC = M.CODSPEC
ORDER BY 
    S.DENUMIRE
```

p.s. although SQL's "shackles of compatibility" (a vendor back in the 1980s supported this and it became standard etc) allows two columns in the same table to have the same name it is probably not a good idea in practice. Also, I'm assuming `AN` is from table `SPECIALIZARE` but could be a typo.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but it still dosent help me i tryed so many ways this is kind of an assigment to make that without using join and only subqueries i know its difficult because i did not post the tabels . I found some reference on this link but its kind of the oposite and yeah you can do that without using join but i just dont know it   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rewriting-subqueries.html 2 tabels Materii with Codmaterie and An and Specializare with Denumire

Comment: to make it simple i just nead to display denumire from specializare and  denumire from materi 2 diferent tabels without using join or where

Comment: @CalinSinea please explain why you have this requirement!

Comment: Cause my teacher is an idiot thats why i have the requirement and i have been browsing for solutions all day

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something silly with a union and a group by.  For example:

```
select max(s_denumire) as s_denumire,
       max(m_denumire) as m_denumire,
       codspec
    from (
        select denumire as s_denumire, null as m_denumire, codspec 
            from specializare
        union all
        select null as s_denumire, denumire as m_denumire, codspec 
            from materii
    )
    group by codspec
```

This produces one row per `codspec`, so it's not exactly like a join.  But you could probably do something with row numbers to address that.  I'll leave that as an exercize for you, since this is evidently homework.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want distinct rows from both tables?

```
SELECT
    SQ.DENUMIRE, SQ.AN
FROM (
    SELECT
        DENUMIRE, AN
    FROM 
        SPECIALIZARE

    UNION

    SELECT
        DENUMIRE, AN
    FROM 
        MATERII
) SQ
ORDER BY
    SQ.DENUMIRE
```

Comment: ... That's not going to give him the same result set layout, so I doubt this is what he wants.